# CSS translate property breaks on Chrome but displays perfect in Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-grid

I'm making a personal website for presentation in GitHub.
https://pablocapobianco.github.io/HelloWorld/
I've made some simple animations in CSS. The flow displays perfect in Firefox but it brakes in Chrome (and Brave). I don't think the problem is the grid display. Any ideas of what the problem may be?

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.pantalla {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  overflow: hidden;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(35%, 45%) auto;
}

.presentacion {
  background: #1c1f1fff;
  z-index: 5;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0%, 45%) auto;
}

.texto {
  scale: 0.8;
  translate: 0vw 10vh;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  z-index: 4;
}

.animacion {
  display: grid;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(124, 179, 189), rgb(19, 93, 100));
  justify-items: center;
}

.luna {
  position: absolute;
  height: 9.5vw;
  opacity: 0.9;
  translate: 0 22vh;
  z-index: 3;
}

.lunaluz {
  position: absolute;
  translate: -0.7vw 20.6vh;
  height: 15vw;
  filter: blur(2px);
  opacity: 0.8;
  rotate: 8deg;
  z-index: 2;
}

.lunaluz.b {
  opacity: 0.065;
}

.nube {
  height: 6.5vw;
  opacity: 0.65;
  animation-name: nube;
  animation-duration: 70s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  filter: blur(0.5px);
  z-index: 4;
}

@keyframes nube {
  0% {
    translate: 30vw 21vh;
  }
  85% {
    translate: -40vw 21vh;
  }
  100% {
    translate: -40vw 21.5vh;
  }
}

.mesa {
  position: absolute;
  translate: 3vw 60vh;
  height: 18vw;
}

.panza {
  animation-name: panza;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  z-index: 7;
}

@keyframes panza {
  0% {
    scale: 1;
  }
  22% {
    scale: 1.06;
  }
  30% {
    scale: 1.06;
  }
  52% {
    scale: 1;
  }
}

.cuadrado {
  position: absolute;
  translate: 41.5vw 0;
  height: 100.2vh;
  z-index: 3;
}

.mesa.humo {
  animation-name: humo;
  animation-duration: 5.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes humo {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  13% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  26% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.humo.a {
  animation-delay: -0.5s;
}

.humo.b {
  animation-delay: -0.25s;
}

path:nth-child(3) {
  fill: #4b87be;
}

.estrella_1 {
  height: 1.1vmin;
  border-radius: 65%;
  background: rgba(255, 180, 218, 0.445);
  animation-name: brillo;
  animation-duration: 7s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  translate: -20vw 18vh;
  rotate: 70deg;
}

@keyframes brillo {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.37vmin 0.37vmin rgba(255, 180, 218, 0.555);
    background: rgba(255, 180, 218, 0.479);
    opacity: 1;
    scale: 1;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.15vmin 0.15vmin rgba(255, 180, 218, 0.5);
    background: rgba(255, 180, 218, 0.384);
    opacity: 0.70;
    scale: 0.8;
  }
  80% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.37vmin 0.37vmin rgba(255, 180, 218, 0.555);
    background: rgba(255, 180, 218, 0.479);
    opacity: 1;
    scale: 1;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.37vmin 0.37vmin rgba(255, 180, 218, 0.555);
    background: rgba(255, 180, 218, 0.479);
    opacity: 1;
    scale: 1;
  }
}

.estrella_2 {
  translate: 16vw 5vh;
  height: 1vmin;
  animation-name: brillo;
  animation-duration: 7s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: -1.11s;
  rotate: 105deg;
  animation-delay: -8.88s;
  border-radius: 65%;
}

.estrella_3 {
  height: 1.1vmin;
  translate: 10vw -10vh;
  rotate: 35deg;
  animation-name: brillo;
  animation-duration: 7s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: -6.66s;
  rotate: 250deg;
  border-radius: 65%;
}

.estrella_4 {
  translate: -3.7vw 3vh;
  height: 0.8vmin;
  animation-name: brillo;
  animation-duration: 7s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: -6.66s;
  rotate: 200deg;
  border-radius: 65%;
}

.estrella_5 {
  translate: -20vw -23vh;
  height: 0.9vmin;
  animation-name: brillo;
  animation-duration: 7s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: -5.55s;
  rotate: 200deg;
  border-radius: 65%;
}

.estrella_6 {
  translate: 15vw -17vh;
  height: 1vmin;
  animation-name: brillo;
  animation-duration: 7s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: -4.44s;
  rotate: 200deg;
  border-radius: 65%;
}

.estrella_7 {
  translate: -15vw -28vh;
  height: 0.8vmin;
  animation-name: brillo;
  animation-duration: 7s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: -4.44s;
  rotate: 200deg;
  border-radius: 65%;
}

.estrella_8 {
  translate: -13vw -45vh;
  height: 1vmin;
  animation-name: brillo;
  animation-duration: 7s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: -7.77s;
  rotate: 170deg;
  border-radius: 65%;
}

.estrella_9 {
  translate: -5vw -75vh;
  height: 0.8vmin;
  animation-name: brillo;
  animation-duration: 7s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: -3.33s;
  rotate: 200deg;
}

.estrella_10 {
  translate: 13.5vw -82vh;
  height: 0.8vmin;
  animation-name: brillo;
  animation-duration: 7s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: -3.33s;
  rotate: 250deg;
  border-radius: 65%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .texto {
    scale: 1.15;
    translate: 0vw 12vh;
  }
  .lunaluz {
    position: absolute;
    translate: -0.7vw 19vh;
    height: 15vw;
    filter: blur(2px);
    opacity: 0.8;
    rotate: 8deg;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo Tamma 2' rel='stylesheet'>
  <script src="prueba.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pantalla">
    <div class="presentacion">
      <img src="texto.svg" class="texto"></img>
      <img src="cuadrado.svg" class="cuadrado"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="animacion">
      <img src="luna.svg" class="luna"></img>
      <img src="lunaluz.svg" class="lunaluz"></img>
      <img src="lunaluz2.svg" class="lunaluz b"></img>
      <img src="nube.svg" class="nube"></img>
      <img src="estrella.svg" class="estrella_1"></img>
      <img src="estrella.svg" class="estrella_2"></img>
      <img src="estrella.svg" class="estrella_3"></img>
      <img src="estrella.svg" class="estrella_4"></img>
      <img src="estrella.svg" class="estrella_5"></img>
      <img src="estrella.svg" class="estrella_6"></img>
      <img src="estrella.svg" class="estrella_7"></img>
      <img src="estrella.svg" class="estrella_8"></img>
      <img src="estrella.svg" class="estrella_9"></img>
      <img src="estrella.svg" class="estrella_10"></img>
      <img src="mesa.svg" class="mesa"></img>
      <img src="panza.svg" class="mesa panza"></img>
      <img src="humo3.svg" class="mesa humo c"></img>
      <img src="humo2.svg" class="mesa humo b"></img>
      <img src="humo1.svg" class="mesa humo a"></img>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: image tags should be written : `<img src="cuadrado.svg" class="cuadrado">`and not alike `<img src="cuadrado.svg" class="cuadrado"></img>` its a self closing tag ;)

Comment: If it's simply HTML and CSS, you might need some vendor prefixes for your CSS to run consistently on different browsers. You can try running your CSS in this : https://autoprefixer.github.io/ EDIT: other comment is also legit.

Comment: You are using a very new CSS property that's only in Editor's Draft, not even Working Draft (let alone Candidate Recommendation or later). You should not expect this to work; it should work only by sheer luck. And it should not be used in production *at all*.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/translate for more info (and browser compat data at the bottom)

Answer (score 4):

Chrome does not support the *translate* property. Instead, use the following formula:

```
transform: translate(x, y)
```

For example,

```
translate: 41.5vw 0
```

becomes

```
transform: translate(41.5vw, 0)
```

You will also need to do this with your rotate tag: `transform: rotate(x)` and your scale tag: `transform: scale(x)`.

Comment: strange, my chrome do apply the transition set in the animation , does this have to do with a specific OS (tested with W7) ... but breaks with edge (86.0.622.51 &  86.0.622.56 ) . however , i would advise too to use the full transform syntax to avoid this kind of troubles ;)

Comment: @Cyrillus Not due to the OS; transform is very new and many stable versions of browsers don´t support it yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is cross-browser css support issue. Would suggest you use some polyfill like [useragentman](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/) for cross browser support.